# ssl connection with tls server and letsencrypt

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, server, lets-encrypt

I try to do ssl connection for my server in c.
i have take this code : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server and I have generated certificate with certbot:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone
```

I have copy cert.pem and privkey.pem present in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/` on my program directory.
but when I try to connect with curl, I get this error:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>       More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

and my server print :

> 1996193792:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 48

thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

That oversimple server does not handle a **chain cert** (or certs), also called intermediate, which every real CA this century requires, including LE. It is suitable only for test certs you generate yourself, or some limited environments like the intranet of a company that runs its own private CA.

Replace `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` on the `cert.pem` file with [`SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_use_certificate_chain_file.html) on the `fullchain.pem` file.

Also, `SSLv23*` methods have (finally!) been replaced by `TLS*` methods as of 1.1.0 in 2016, although the obsolete names remain as synonyms for now.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work !
but can u explain why i need to use fullchain.pem instead cert.pem ?

Comment: @Luzwitz: in general https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO16297.html and for LE specifically https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ (in addition to their own root being offline, to get started initially they were cross-signed under IdenTrust) or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-